# equal Operator in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, equality

Why does this:

```
(every (lambda (x) (equal "a" x)) "aaaaa")
```

and this:

```
(every (lambda (x) (equal "a" x)) "a")
```

return `NIL`, while this:

```
(every (lambda (x) (equal "a" x)) '("a" "a" "a" "a"))
```

returns `T`?  I thought `every` worked on all sequences.

Comment: `(,pedant it is a function not an operator)

Comment: @d11wtq can you explain?

Comment: lisp doesn't have 'operators', it only has functions. When you do `(equal x y)`, you're applying the `equal` function to `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always find it out yourself. A test is only a few seconds away if you use an interactive Lisp system:

```
CL-USER 1 > (every (lambda (x) (equal "a" x)) "a")
NIL
```

Above returns NIL.

Now use the Common Lisp function `DESCRIBE` to get the data described.

```
CL-USER 2 > (every (lambda (x)
                     (describe x)
                     (describe "a")
                     (equal "a" x))
                   "a")

#\a is a CHARACTER
Name                "Latin-Small-Letter-A"
Code                97
Bits                0
Font                0
Function-Key-P      NIL
```

So the value of `x` is a character. The character `#\a`.

```
"a" is a SIMPLE-BASE-STRING
0      #\a
NIL
```

The type of "a" is `SIMPLE-BASE-STRING` (here in LispWorks).

If you look at the definition of `EQUAL`, then you can see that a character and a string are never equal, because they are of different types.

```
CL-USER 3 > (equal #\a "a")
NIL
```

Answer (score 13):

Because in case 1 and case 2 you compare `"a"` and `#\a`, but in last case you compare `"a"` and `"a"`.  Strings' elements are chars, not other strings.

For example:

```
(every (lambda (x) (equal #\a x)) "aaaaa")
=> T
```

Another alternative is to coerce `x` to string:

```
(every (lambda (x) (equal "a" (string x))) "aaaaa")
```